# Longest palindromic Substring length

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

Below code gives me longest palindromic subsequence length. How can I modify the code to get longest palindromic sub**string** length?

```java
public static int lp(String str, int i, int j, int ans) {    
    if (i == str.length() || j <= 0)
        return ans;

    if (i > j)
        return ans;

    if (i == j)
        return ans + 1;

    if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {
        int a = lp(str, i + 1, j, ans);
        int b = lp(str, i, j - 1, ans);
        int c = lp(str, i + 1, j - 1, ans + 2);
        ans = Math.max(Math.max(a, b), c);
        return ans;
    } else {
        int a = lp(str, i + 1, j, ans);
        int b = lp(str, i, j - 1, ans);
        ans = Math.max(a, b);
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Here is an example call:

```java
    String s = "sbsncjss"; 
    // longest subsequence length is 5 and longest substring length is 3
    System.out.println("Ans is " + lp(s, 0, s.length() - 1, 0));
```

Comment: Search for Manacher's algorithm

Comment: @r3mainer and in the above algo how can i print the value of longes palindromic subsequence

Comment: Wait, are you asking for the longest palindromic subsequence? I thought you just presented the code for it.... and were asking about palindromic substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I modify the code to get longest palindromic substring length

You then need to exclude the cases where characters are skipped. When your code is about to skip a character, the search can continue, but with `ans` reset to 0.

So:

```java
public static int lp(String str, int i, int j, int ans) {
    if (i == str.length() || j <= 0)
        return ans;

    if (i > j)
        return ans;

    if (i == j)
        return ans + 1;

    if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {
        int a = lp(str, i + 1, j, 0);   // <-- reset!
        int b = lp(str, i, j - 1, 0);   // <-- reset!
        int c = lp(str, i + 1, j - 1, ans + 2);
        ans = Math.max(Math.max(a, b), c);
        return ans;
    } else {
        int a = lp(str, i + 1, j, 0);   // <-- reset!
        int b = lp(str, i, j - 1, 0);   // <-- reset!
        ans = Math.max(a, b);
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Be aware that although this works, there are more efficient algorithms for finding the longest palindrome **substring**. But they are completely different from the algorithm you presented for the longest palindrome **subsequence**, so it would not be a matter of just making some changes.

Comment: @Tricot My code gives the length of longest subsequence length.i sit possible to the Subsesequence string too?

Comment: Sure, but that is a different question. You were asking what needed to change to get the length of the longest sub*string*, which I think I did. If you have a new question, please ask a new question (after you have tried to do it yourself of course)

Comment: OK going to ask.Just wante dopne clarification.Do i need to to write separate code for that or i can modify the existing one to get the answer?

Comment: And i am aware there are better algorithms for the finding longest paloindrome substring But i am trying to get answer using recusrion

Comment: You should certainly write it as a new question (using the [Ask Question] button), and it is important that you include code that shows your attempt at doing it, and a description what goes wrong with that attempt.

Comment: sure let me try first ..not sure how I can tag you in that question .

Comment: You can post a link to your new question here, and I'll notice. But surely there are many members that will be able to deal with your question, even when I am offline.

Comment: i posted the question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72839667/longest-increasing-subsequence-length-and-value