# Longest Increasing Subsequence Length and Value

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Below code gives the length of longest increasing subsequence. Code works fine.

**Input:** nums = [10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]
**Output:** 4
**Explanation:** The longest increasing subsequence is [2,3,7,101], therefore the length is 4.

With the help of below code I want to print which array elements are part of the subsequence i.e [2,3,7,101],
How can I do it? Or do I need to write completely different code?

Is there any generic way to do for other problems to do like longest palindromic subsequence?

```
public int lengthOfLIS(int[] nums) {
  return helper(nums, 0, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
}

public int helper(int[] arr, int i, int prev) {
  if (i == arr.length)
    return 0;
  int include = 0;
  if (arr[i] > prev) {
    include = 1 + helper(arr, i + 1, arr[i]);
  }
  int exclude = helper(arr, i + 1, prev);
  return Math.max(include, exclude);
}
```

Comment: I thought [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms) includes a demonstration of how to do that.

Comment: @גלעדברקן yes for tabulation  approach.I wanted to know how to do it in Recursion solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public void longestIncreasingSubsequence(int[] numbers)
   {
       List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
       List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
       for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
           temp.add(numbers[i]);
           if ( i + 1 == numbers.length || numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1])
           {
               if(temp.size() >= result.size())
               {
                   result.clear();
                   result.addAll(temp);
               }
               temp.clear();
           }
       }
       System.out.println(result);
   }
```

Try this

I got your point. Plz Check my new code

```
  public void longestSubSequence(int[] nums)
    {
        int index=0;
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
         while (index<nums.length)
        {
            int val=nums[index];
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            temp.add(val);
            for (int i = index+1; i < nums.length; i++) {
                int currentVal = nums[i];
                if (val < currentVal)
                {
                    val= currentVal;
                    temp.add(currentVal);
                }

            }
            if(temp.size()>= result.size())
            {
                result.clear();
                result.addAll(temp);
                temp.clear();
            }
            index++;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: ur code gives wrong answer.
[3, 7, 101]

Comment: Input: nums = [10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]
why 2,3,7,101 ? where is number 5 ?

Comment: [2,5,7,101] This should be printed

Comment: it's really confuse . if the Input is [10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]  so we can see 2 increasing subsequences are [2,5] and [3,7,101].

Comment: its not.Question is to print LONGEST increasing subsequence